# facebook sdk only public sharing

Tags: java, android, android-studio, facebook-sdk-4.0

I have manage to share with Facebook sdk from my own app.

my question is,how can i get which privacy the user selected?

```
         Example: public / friends / only me
```

And if i can decide for the user which privacy?

thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a privacy field in the Post API: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.8/post

You can only set a privacy that includes less friends than the default privacy setting a user selected for your App:

> This field cannot be used to set a more open privacy setting than the
>   one granted.

Source: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.8/user/feed#publish

Comment: Hey,first of all thank you for the quick answer ! I understood how to use the API but i have got this error = **An active access token must be used to query information about the current user**  and i  kind of got stuck... can you help me a bit more? thanks

Comment: not sure what your api call is, but you need to use an active user token, that´s what the error message tells you. you need to implement user login: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/

Comment: yes i know but iam using the **share dialog** to share a link and not login first

Comment: you have to authorize a user in order to get the privacy information after sharing. may i ask what the use case for this is? why do you want to know the privacy setting?

Comment: i am developing an game app. I want the user to be able to share a link to my app but and know if he shared with public privacy or "only me". because if he share to public i want to give the user a prize

Comment: well, that´s not allowed anyway. you can´t reward users in any way for sharing something. that´s why i asked, people usually want to know the privacy status for those kind of things. you need to read the platform policy.

Comment: I meant with the in app rewards not money(if that want you mean)(?).

Comment: "you can´t reward users in any way" - it does not matter how you want to reward users, it´s not allowed.